# Docker process showing only on Ubuntu 18.04 but not Hyper Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, shell, docker, container

I usually use my Hyper terminal for programming purposes, which should be the same (uses WSL 2) as my Ubuntu 18.04 WSL 2.

I can run the same docker commands on them, but for some reason when docker is running a MongoDB container the command `ps aux | grep mongo` doesn't show up on my Hyper terminal, but it does show up on my Ubuntu shell. Any idea why this is or how I can fix this?